# replace na in cut function with specific number in r

Tags: r

Assuming I need to add a column to existing tibble age_group that bins age into groups: 0-14, 15-24, 25-44, 45-64, 65+

my code and output

```
  p1<data %>% mutate(age=2018-birth_year,age_group=cut(age,breaks=c(14,24,44,64),replace_na=("65+"))
  $ age                     <dbl> 26, 49, 72, 24, 27, 36, 60, 29, 58, 42, 29, 33, 44, 42, 50, 42, 30, 28, 26, 26, 29, 33, 38, 23, 38, 26, 37, 27, 27, 40, 35, 29, 52~
  $ age_group               <fct> "(24,44]", "(44,64]", NA, "(14,24]", "(24,44]", "(24,44]", "(44,64]", "(24,44]", "(44,64]", "(24,44]", "(24,44]", "(24,44]", "(24,
```

expected

```
  $ age                     <dbl> 26, 49, 72, 24, 27, 36, 60, 29, 58,
  $ age_group               <fct> "(24,44]", "(44,64]", "65+", "(14,24]",
```

Not sure how to fix the code to replace numbers greater than 65 with "65+",and leaves NA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the breaks till infinity and use the `labels` argument in `cut` to assign labels as per your choice.

```
library(dplyr)

data <- data %>% 
         mutate(age=2018-birth_year,
                age_group = cut(age,breaks=c(0, 14,24,44,64, Inf), 
                         labels = c('14-24', '24-44', '44-64', '65+')))
```

If you want to change only one label (`65+`) and keep rest of them as it is do :

```
data <- data %>% 
          mutate(age=2018-birth_year,
                 age_group = cut(age,breaks=c(0, 14,24,44,64)),  
                          age_group = factor(replace(as.character(age_group), 
                        is.na(age_group), '65+'), c(levels(age_group), '65+')))
```

and with `forcats::fct_explicit_na`

```
data <- data %>% 
          mutate(age=2018-birth_year,
                 age_group = cut(age,breaks=c(0, 14,24,44,64)), 
                 age_group = forcats::fct_explicit_na(age_group, '65+'))
```

Comment: Hi,  I want to keep  the output  like above "(24,44]", "(44,64]", "65+", "(14,24]", how should I modify the code ?

Comment: Yes,but I think the code should be much shorter. NO,all positive numbers.

Comment: Your data is still not reproducible which we can copy easily. I updated the answer to use `fct_explicit_na`.

Comment: Same result when I use replace_na=("65+"),maybe fix it in cut function ?

Comment: @Kee I don't get the same result. There is no `replace_na` argument in `cut` so you cannot use it there. Please check the documentation at `?cut`. When I check `levels(data$age_group)` I get `[1] "(0,14]"  "(14,24]" "(24,44]" "(44,64]" "65+" `. I guess that is what your expected output is.

Comment: As mentioned earlier "65+" is present for me and works for me. If you are still not able to make it work for your data and need further help please consider to add data in a reproducible format. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: Hi there， I want to just replace numbers greater than 65 and leave NA, how should I fix ？Thank you ！

Comment: The code that you have tried `age_group=cut(age,breaks=c(14,24,44,64)` already turns anything above 65 to be `NA`.

Comment: Does fct_explicit_na make all na to “65+” ？I mean just check numbers greater than 65 become "65+" and leave the rest of na.

Comment: Use my first approach then and assign `labels` as per your choice. `labels = c('(14-24]', '(24-44]', '(44-64]', '65+')`. Everything above 65 would be 65+ and `NA` would remain as `NA`.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple:

```r
data$age_group = cut(data$age,breaks=c(0, 14, 24, 44, 64, Inf)
levels(data$age_group)[6] <- "65+"
```